# MySQL Error 1366 when converting JSON to TEXT with certain characters

Tags: mysql

UPDATE: Below is additional information showing how TEXT is behaving differently from JSON and Global Variables with the same data. Even stranger, the CHARSET and COLLATION of the var_json and @var_char1 are the EXACT SAME as the TEXT variable (utf8mb4/utf8mb4_unicode_ci).

```
DECLARE var_char text;
DECLARE var_json json;
-- The CHARSET and COLLATION of var_char is utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci
SET var_json = '{"This": "• ® is a test"}'; -- Works Fine
SET @var_char1 = 'This • ® is a test'; -- Works Fine
SET var_char = 'This • ® is a test'; -- ERROR 1366 \x95 \xAE
SET var_char = CONVERT('This • ® is a test' USING utf8); -- Replaces specials with ? ? and works
SET var_char = CONVERT('This • ® is a test' USING utf8mb4); -- returns NULL ?!
```

Why on earth won't the TEXT variable accept and keep the special characters when it shares the exact same charset/collation as the global/JSON variables, which keep it just fine?

===

I have an issue where I must extract JSON chunks and convert them to TEXT strings for internal processing; the problem is MySQL is choking with Error 1366 on simple characters like • (/x95). If I use a Global Variable, it's not a problem (e.g. @var rather than var TEXT); this seems to only happen with TEXT variables.

My Charset is: utf8mb4
My Collation is: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
My SQL version is: 8.0.18
Environment: Windows 10

The below code always produces: Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\x95' for column 'var_char' at row 1

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE empowercrm_main.test_proc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_char text;
    set var_char = '•';
END
```

Note if I use a GLOBAL variable (e.g. @var_char) it works fine. But I shouldn't need to use a global variable to do this!

MySQL has been a nightmare to work with when it comes to collation and character issues. I'm left scratching my head on this one. Also, if this character is causing the variable assignment to error out, what other characters will do the same thing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts on this? The only way I was able to work around this was to convert the string to UTF8 then back again to UTF8MB4, which seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the encoding of my connection. I was using default -> Current Windows Code Page. When I switched to utf8mb4 -> Unicode (UTF-8) the problem disappeared. What is very strange is the failure was taking place in very complex stored procedures that all called each other; why it was leveraging a connection encoding is beyond me as the server/system was issuing the calls and its encoding is set properly.